# Сихронизация потока относительно основного потока приложения

Tags: c#, многопоточность, winforms

Классическое оконное приложение. Но до запуска любого окна - прямо в методе Main - запускаю поток - с помощью которого делаю проверку обновлений. В любом раскладе, при окончании потока, должно появится какие-то формы, но их показ - по правилам - должно произойти в основном потоке приложения. В классическом исполнении - в коде исполняемом в потоке - должно быть что-то вроде:

```
public void ShowMainForm(string result)
{
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(this.ShowMainForm), result);
}
else
{
    //делаю что-то уже в потоке this
}
}
```

Вышеописанный код работет если this наследует Control. Но в моем случае, кодга нету ниодного созданного контрола - относительно чего проверить что код будет выполнен в главном потоке приложения?
Надеюсь я ясно изъснился.

**UPD:**
Начало [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834378/managing-threads-in-an-net-winform-application)

Вот схема выполнения -

1. вход в программу
2. запускается поток на поверку
3. на время выполнения потока показывается инфо-форма.
4. при окончании выполнения потока либо показывается главная форма, либо форма обновления

Вот такая вот схема.

Comment: >Надеюсь я ясно изъснился.

не очень

Comment: Может просто проверку обновления вынести в события Form.Shown, и будет относительно чего проверять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У потока есть контекст синхронизации. При создании фонового потока этот контекст надо передавать создаваемому потоку, и тогда можно будет делать синхронизацию через него.

Answer (score 0):

А что вам мешает например воспользоватся классом [**BackgroundWorker**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), а связь с ним наладить через делегат **OnProgressChanged**

Comment: а он работает в не-WinForm-овском окружении?

Comment: А Вы проверьте? И что значит - не в винформовском? В консоле?
BackgroundWorker - это компонентная обёртка по сути над классом Thread. И зачем вам не винформ, в Вашем случае? Вы же показываете форму информации? Запускайте главную форму, ей ставити визибле фалс, запускайте в ней показ формы информации и баграун воркер. ну и по результатам или показывайте форму обновления или нет.

Comment: гмм... а ведь идея...

Answer (score 0):

[Вот тут](http://code.google.com/p/gui-thread-synco/) решение. Обьяснять не буду - смотрите код. Будут вопросы - задавайте.

Comment: Я, возможно, чего-то не знаю, но почему нельзя было сделать, например, так:

    var syncControl = new Control();
    syncControl.CreateControl();
    // Это дает гарантию выполнения в UI потоке.
    syncControl.BeginInvoke(() => whatever);